# Should I place a toggle form button outside of <form></form>?

Tags: wordpress, forms, toggle

I have a simple form on my main page. It needs to be toggle-able (is that a word?) between the simple version and the detailed version using a button. Where do I put the code for the button, inside or outside the form element? I read online that the submit button should be within the form, so I'm guessing a toggle button should also be there? But I'd rather ask more experienced people. Also, how would I make the forms retain the same content that the user typed when toggleing?

This is for a form I'm making on Wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend placing the toggle button outside of the `<form>` element and then use jQuery (or plain javascript) to handle the switching between the simple and detailed versions of the form. I'm not exactly clear what you had in mind for the simple and detailed versions of the form, but this approach should be easy to adapt to your purposes.

You can give the advanced form fields the same class (e.g. "detailed"), have them hidden by default in your CSS, and then have them appear when the toggle button is clicked using jQuery.

The values inputted into the detailed form fields won't get lost when the button is toggled; the values are still there, but just hidden. They'd still get submitted when the form submit button was clicked.

This is the toggle and `<form>` code.

```
<button id="form-toggle">Toggle Detailed Form Fields</button>
<form id="test-form" action="action_page.php">
    <p>First name: <input type="text" name="firstname" value=""></p>
    <p>Last name: <input type="text" name="lastname" value=""></p>
    <p class="detailed">Email: <input type="email" name="email" value=""></p>
    <p class="detailed">Phone: <input type="tel" name="phone" value=""></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Submit"></p>
</form>
```

This is the CSS you should place in your stylesheet, it makes the detailed form fields hidden by default:

```
.detailed {
    display: none;
}
```

This is the jQuery code that you could enqueue as an external .js file in your **functions.php** file or before the `</body>` of your **footer.php** file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        $('#form-toggle').click(function() {
            $('.detailed').toggle('fast');
        });
    });
</script>
```